# MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED format

Tags: android

Can anyone show me how to format the MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED to the human readable date format. I read in the docs that the time is in seconds. So i simply multiply it  by 1000 and use the SimpleDateFormat . Here  is my code

```
    Date d=new Date(mills*1000);
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    return df.format(d);
```

This returns a String 25-35-2012 that off course is not correct. Any help with this ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use capital `M`, `m` refers to `minute in hour` while `M` refer to `Month in year`.

see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for further info